# meta_query filter: get posts where two of the three conditions matches

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm on the way to develop a filter that shows the related posts based on a few questions the user answered before. To control the filters sensitivity, i have to set a number of how many conditions have to match.

So let's imagine following `WP Query`:

```
$rd_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'question 1',
            'value' => 'answer 1'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'question 2',
            'value' => 'answer 3'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'question 3',
            'value' => 'answer 2'
        )
    )
) );
```

In this case, there are three conditions that must match.
`The question: is there a way that only two of the three conditions must match?`
The number of questions and of the matches is variable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way might be a  nested `meta_query`:

```
$rd_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        // Update main relation to OR
        'relation' => 'OR',

        // create three nested queries that require
        // the different possible pairs
        array(
            // I believe this "AND" is the default but added for the example
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'question 1',
                'value' => 'answer 1'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'question 2',
                'value' => 'answer 2'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'question 1',
                'value' => 'answer 1'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'question 3',
                'value' => 'answer 3'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'question 2',
                'value' => 'answer 2'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'question 3',
                'value' => 'answer 3'
            ),
        ),
    )
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forget to say that the number of questions and of the matches is variable. I have edited the question.